# ConvertFrom-StringData Duplicates

Tags: powershell

how best to de-duplicate any data for this line? the only issue seems to be ***ConvertFrom-StringData***; if I remove that one bit I get no errors ...

here's the code:

```
$remotefilehash =  (($remoteFiles | Where-Object { -not ($_ | Select-String -Quiet -NotMatch -Pattern '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )') }) -replace '^[a-f0-9]{32}(  )', '$0=  ' -join "`n") | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

and the error

```
ConvertFrom-StringData : Data item 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e' in line 'a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-10-08 21-46-21.mov' is already 
defined.
```

the $remotefiles var has data like:

```
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-10-08 21-46-21 (2).mov
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-10-08 21-46-21.mov
```

so I only need ONE of these files and since they both have the same checksum I don't care which path

I'm thinking maybe a try/catch on the "is already defined" ? maybe thats better b/c I can run a different command if it does happen

Comment: Not sure how you expect us to help without having data to replicate the error

Comment: I assume `$remotefiles` is an array of strings and not a single string?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thats correct

Comment: I don't get it, if you only want to get all hashes and dont care about the path, why not match all occurrences of `[a-f0-9]{32}` and use a hashset to deduplicate? your solution seem to be overly complicated

Comment: I still need the sum + path eventually but for the de-duplication I do not need it

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do it like this, with just a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) to loop on each string, [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) and [`$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches) for regex comparison and generating the objects, and a [`HashSet<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) that ensures the code doesn't output duplicated hashes:

```
$remoteFiles = @'
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  path/to/thing/2022-10-08 21-46-21 (2).mov
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e  =  path/to/thing/2022-10-08 21-46-21.mov
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707f  =  path/to/otherstuff
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707f  =  path/to/otherstuff2
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707f  =  path/to/otherstuff3
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$hash = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
$remoteFiles | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match '(?<hash>^[a-f0-9]{32})[\s=]{5}(?<path>.+)' -and $hash.Add($Matches['hash'])) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Hash = $Matches['hash']
            Path = $Matches['path']
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hash                             Path
----                             ----
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707e path/to/thing/2022-10-08 21-46-21 (2).mov
a3512c98c9e159c021ebbb76b238707f path/to/otherstuff
```